# Verify sane image dimensions in Java without ImageMagick or ImageIO

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, javax.imageio

I have a thing that processes images with ImageMagick. ImageMagick has a reproducible bug that causes it to more or less lock a system on certain falsely-large images:

https://hackerone.com/reports/390

To avoid this, I'm using ImageIO to load the image before sending it to ImageMagick, because the ImageIO.read() explodes when it finds an absurd number of pixels (it throws an exception with the message: "width*height > Integer.MAX_VALUE!").

The problem is that ImageIO is not as tolerant of corrupt or poorly-formed images as ImageMagick, and I don't want to chase down and handle the known and unknown edge cases that ImageMagick just deals with fine.

I'm hoping to verify the sane dimensions of a JPEG, PNG, TIF, ICO, and GIF image without using ImageMagick's load or ImageIO.read(). I could limit to, say, 50 MP if need be.

Comment: And ImageMagick's ping method wouldn't work for you?

Comment: @emcconville While I definitively prefer using ImageIO over ImageMagick myself, I think it would make more sense to chose only one library. ImageMagick's ping sounds like it should do the job.

Comment: I'm in agreement @haraldK. Perhaps the OP can clarify. Are you seeking advise to building a fault-tolerance system, or a technique to eliminate the dependency of such libraries? As haraldK pointed out  [in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32376690/438117), building your own would be a large effort, and would still be vulnerable to other DoS attacks (like zipbombs impeded in imagedata.)

Comment: ImageMagick's ping (loading on basic file info) will not help here, because it is determining the dimensions of the image in the usual manner. My goal is to prevent ImageMagick from locking the system when it loads the "poisonous" image referenced here: [Dubiously Large Image](https://hackerone-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/production/000/000/128/5f5a974e5f67ab7a11d2d92bd40f8997969f2f17/lottapixel.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFXIS7KJADBA4QQA&Expires=1441377834&Signature=r9dY4NTso82RgbwIE9NgTsviF4Y%3D)

Comment: There is currently too much that relies on ImageMagick to replace it in a timely manner.

Comment: I don't hink you got what @emcconville (or myself) meant. It's not enough to just *run* the ping command, you need to check the image dimensions from the command and act on it, if you think they are too large... It's the same with my answer below. In both cases, *you need to decide* based on the input, wether you should attempt to load it or not.

Comment: ImageMagick does not correctly deduce that the image linked to above is 64250x64250.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ImageIO to obtain the `ImageReader`, then query the `ImageReader` for width and height, without actually loading the image.

```
try (ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input)) {
    Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
    if (readers.hasNext()) {
        ImageReader reader = readers.next();
        reader.setInput(stream);

        // Get width/height of first image in file
        // (alternatively, use getNumImages() and loop over all images)
        int w = reader.getWidth(0);
        int h = reader.getHeight(0);

        if (w * h > SANE_MAX_SIZE) {
            // TODO: Handle image too large
        }
    }
}
```

You might still have the problem with ImageIO being less fault tolerant though.

I recommend using either my own TwelveMonkeys ImageIO plugins (supports TIFF, ICO and adds better JPEG support), but I guess you could also use Apache Commons Imaging or other library.

The last resort is to write code to parse all these formats yourself. But I think the chance of that having less bugs than an existing solution is small, without a considerable effort on your part... ;-)

Comment: I'm afraid this won't catch the "poisonous" image referred to here:

https://hackerone-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/production/000/000/128/5f5a974e5f67ab7a11d2d92bd40f8997969f2f17/lottapixel.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFXIS7KJADBA4QQA&Expires=1441377834&Signature=r9dY4NTso82RgbwIE9NgTsviF4Y%3D

The dimensions are still reported as sane via ImageReader, and ImageMagick will still try to allocate memory for 4000 megapixels on load.

Comment: What do you mean by "reported as sane"? This image is 64250 x 64250 pixels. The `w` and `h` in the code will reflect that, but it doesn't report anything. I don't know what your limit for "sane" is, that's why I left it to you to implement, but it's easy to do once you know the limit.

Comment: @Tremelune Updated answer to make things a little more clear.

Comment: Interesting. I must have botched the test I have for this the first time around, as I was not seeing the width and height reported as 64250. On a second look, both the Sun and Twelve Monkeys JPEGReaders are reporting this correctly.